# $state.go doesnt call resolve method when going to parent

Tags: angular-ui-router

I have the following code for go back button:

```
function goBack() {
        var id = $scope.$parent.information && $scope.$parent.information .id;

        // you can either come back to the one of two possible states
        $state.go($state.$current.parent.name, { id: id || $ctrl.groupId }, {reload:true});
    }
```

When I run this code, the resolve method defined for the parent state doesn't get called, and no network call is made, as a result.

The states that I check are defined in the following way:

```
.state('home.groups.history.details', {
            url: '/:id',
            controller: 'firstController',
            templateUrl: '...',
            resolve: {
                detailsModel: function (detailsService, $stateParams) {
                    return detailsService.getGroupDetails($stateParams.id, true)
                        .then(function (result) {
                            return result.data;
                        });
                        // .catch(function(){});
                }
            }                
        })
        .state('home.groups.history.details.specific', {
            url: '/:specificId',
            controller: 'secondController',
            templateUrl: '...',
            resolve: {
                specificDetailsModel: function ($stateParams, detailsService) {
                    return detailsService.getSpecific($stateParams.specificId)
                        .then(function (result) {
                            return result.data;
                        });
                        // .catch(function(){});
                }
            }
        })
```

What do I have to do, in order to make goBack method call the resolve function when going back to parent state?

Thanks

Comment: Is `$state.go('^', { id: id || $ctrl.groupId }, {reload:true});` works?

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't. I was able to fix it be assigning a new state param and sending a unique value to it.

Comment: Oh, good to hear. So it's inheritance issue between parameters? Maybe if you add `inherit: false` to the parameters it could also work the old way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is based on an answer supplied here: [ui-router does not run a parent state's resolve promise when using $state.go()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354046/ui-router-does-not-run-a-parent-states-resolve-promise-when-using-state-go)

In order to reload parent when all states params are the same, is to crate a new state param and assure that its unique every go back. My solution:

```
function goBack() {
    var id = $scope.$parent.information && $scope.$parent.information .id;

    // you can either come back to the one of two possible states
    $state.go($state.$current.parent.name, { id: id || $ctrl.groupId, timeSpan: Date.now() });
}
```

Thus, timespan will be different every time we call it. Also, add timeSpan to parent state params:

```
.state('home.groups.history.details', {
        url: '/:id',
        controller: 'firstController',
        params: {timeSpan: undefined},
        templateUrl: '...',
        resolve: {
            detailsModel: function (detailsService, $stateParams) {
                return detailsService.getGroupDetails($stateParams.id, true)
                    .then(function (result) {
                        return result.data;
                    });
                    // .catch(function(){});
            }
        }                
    })
```